# Does Ryanair accept the image of the boarding pass on a mobile phone?

Tags: tickets, ryanair

... or must it be from their app?

I received a boarding pass (in PDF format) from my agent for my return flight, while already at my destination (Ryanair does not issue them sooner, I was told). I can hardly print it here.

Is showing it on my mobile phone acceptable at the airport?
Their FAQ mentions an app of theirs which basically does the same (shows the boarding information).

Comment: Why can you not print it there?  Your place of accommodation may be able to print it for you.

Comment: With an airline, which is interested in making customers happy it might indeed work. For RyanAir however not. For them this is a way for charging extra.

Comment: Use the app just to be sure. You can always delete it later.

Answer (score 5):

Nope!  (Atleast that was so in 2014)

> @Minezey Hi Simon, we don't accept PDF boarding pass, you will need to print it out. Have you saved your boarding pass on your phone? MC

**[Twitter @Ryanair](https://twitter.com/ryanair/status/507144011770241024?lang=en)**

Answer (score 5):

Ryanair policies change regularly, but as of September 2017 the message below appears at the point at which you or your agent downloads the PDF boarding pass: 'This is not a mobile boarding pass and MUST be printed for use.'

That's not to say that showing the PDF on your mobile phone at the airport would *definitely* be unacceptable to Ryanair, but if it was rejected, they did give you fair warning.

[image: Ryanair boarding pass printing]

Comment: Ryanair policies change not quite so regularly...

Comment: I found from other sources too, that officially the app image is the only thing accepted on a phone. Unofficially the PDF works too (maybe not always, it worked for me this week).

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that sometimes Ryanair requires Visa check for non-eu citizens. In such case you have to print it anyway.

The main information is the QR code (the rectangular bar code) which has all information about ticket. There is no difference is it printed or on the phone. You can even show it from the watch. So I see no reasons it will not work with showing it from PDF.

During last my trip people were just putting their phone to the bar code reader, it was not important whether it is app, screenshot or pdf.

Meanwhile you should check whether the check in through the app is supported in the airport on the official site.